# CMake 3.9 now creates "autogen" projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, cmake, visual-studio-2017

We're using CMake, Qt, and Visual Studio. Many of our projects are configured to run automoc, via passing `AUTOMOC ON` to `add_library`.

We recently updated to CMake 3.9.1, and Visual Studio now shows an additional project for every automoc'd library.  For example, we now have a "Core" project and a "Core_autogen" project in our solution.

(this occurs in both VS2015 and VS2017, and both Qt 5.8 and 5.9.1)

This has a few annoying consequences:

- Nearly double the number of projects, adding a lot of visual clutter.
- Automoc no longer runs when building an individual project through the UI, which can lead to subtle bugs when debugging build issues for a specific project.

Does anyone know if there's a way to restore the previous CMake behavior for autogen?

Or barring that, some way to at least reduce the visual clutter of the autogen projects?

Comment: Maybe `set_property( GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON )` will help?

Comment: Check out [issue 17205](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17205) in the CMake gitlab. It reports the `_autogen` part of this problem and links to a merge request which is expected to address it (currently targeted at the 3.10.0 release).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a regression and supposed to be fixed in CMake 3.10.
The CMake bug report is here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17205

Comment: Same problem with CMake 3.22 for me...

Answer (score 7):

According to the CMake v3.9 Documentation, you could use [AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR.html) to move the generated files to a different folder.

By default CMake uses `<dir>/<target-name>_autogen` where:

> `<dir>` is [CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html) and `<target-name>` is [NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/NAME.html)

Or from the [AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) property you could use:

> The global property [AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_gbl/AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER.html) can be used to group the automoc targets together in an IDE, e.g. in MSVS.
>
> The global property [AUTOGEN_SOURCE_GROUP](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_gbl/AUTOGEN_SOURCE_GROUP.html) can be used to group files generated by AUTOMOC together in an IDE, e.g. in MSVS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but that doesn't quite help.

AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER sets the location where the generated files (eg. mocs_compilation.cpp) are stored.  CMake still creates the "_autogen" projects regardless.  Before 3.9, CMake ran moc as part of a project's prebuild step.  Now it seems to create an extra project for every automoc'd project.

Answer (score 6):

This collects all autogen projects in one folder:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER AutoMoc)
```

[image]